# How do I access a private constructor in a class from the main function in C++?

Tags: c++, class, c++11, inheritance, c++14

I have a program where I have a super-class called Flower and sub-classes Rose, Lily, Jasmine.

The flower protected members with 2 variables describing the feature of the flower and public members with getter functions and a pure-virtual function (called string getColor()) printing the color of the sub-class flower. It also has a public member function that prints the characteristic of each flower (void printFlower(string name)).

I am trying to implement the class for Rose, Lily and Jasmine and I have to do so without using the public access modifier in the class. So, everything in the class must either be protected or private (even the constructor). I know that Rose, Lily, and Jasmine publicly inherit from the parent class Flower.

In my main function, I have this:

```
int main(){

Rose rose;
Flower * pointer = &rose;
rose.printFlower("red");

Lily lily;
pointer = &lily;
lily.printFlower("white"); // not sure what color lilies are

Jasmine jas;
pointer = &jas;
jas.printFlower("orange");
return 0;
}
```

My task is to not use the public access modifier in the Rose, Lily and Jasmine classes but I can publicly inherit Flower if I want to. So, is there any way to use a private Constructor (using Flower as a friend) or something like that to accomplish this?

**EDIT: I realized how little info I provided so I am editing the question here. The following is the declaration for the Flower super-class which I cannot change.**

```
class Flower{
protected:
    bool isPopular;
    bool isThorny;

public:
    Flower(bool isPopular, bool isThorny){
        this->isPopular = isPopular;
        this->isThorny = isThorny;
    }

    bool getIsPopular(){
        return this->isPopular;
    }

    bool getIsThorny(){
        return this->isThorny;
    }
    virtual string getColor() = 0;

    void printFlower(string name){
        cout << "A " << name << " has '" << this->getColor() << "' color and is "
    << (this->getIsThorny()?"":"not ") << "thorny, and is " << (this->getIsPopular()?"":"not ")
    << "very popular." << endl;
    }
};
```

My task is basically the following in the image:
[Task for declaring derived-classes](https://i.stack.imgur.com/HR7xM.png)

The task will just run main and print the printFlower function when called from main. The only restriction I have is that I cannot use the public access modifier inside the class declaration for Rose, Lily and Jasmine but I can and do inherit from flower publicly. ie. class Rose:public Flower(){}
Is there any way I can write Rose, Lily and Jasmine by making all its members private or protected?

Comment: Showing classes `Flower`/`Rose` would be more interesting...

Comment: Tongue-in-cheek answer: define `Rose`, `Lily`, etc. using `struct` instead of `class`, then you won't have to use the `public` keyword.

Comment: So you want to create instances of these classes but you don't want make constructors public. Any reason for that beyond "can this be done?"?

Comment: `friend` or a `static` member function? ("Factory function", if you want)

Comment: Apart from using a `struct` instead of a `class` (which means default access is `public` rather than `private`) the only way to access `private` members if from a `friend`.     The constraint not to use the `public` modifier seems dumb though.

Comment: I agree; it is kinda dumb. How would I use friend in this case though? I edited the question a lot

Comment: The image that you added doesn't show the requirement not to use the public access modifier inside the class declaration. Are you sure it's part of the exercise requirements? If so, probably your teacher wants you to use struct. But it can be wise to consult him/her.

Answer (score 0):

You're apparently being guided towards a certain take on the Factory pattern. The solution is to define a factory function in `Flower` which will do the instantiation.

I will show how this can be done. To demonstrate why this might be useful , I will make the factory into a simple translator from runtime parameters to a compile-time type:

```
class Flower
{
public:
  virtual ~Flower() = default;

  static std::unique_ptr<Flower> create(const std::string &species)
  {
    std::unique_ptr<Flower> result;
    if (species == "rose")
    {
        result = std::make_unique<Rose>();
    }   
    else if (species == "lily")
    {
        result = std::make_unique<Lily>();
    }  
    else 
    {
        throw std::invalid_argument("No such flower");
    }
    return result;
  }
};

class Rose : public Flower
{
  friend Flower;
  Rose() = default;
};

class Lily : public Flower
{
  friend Flower;
  Lily() = default;
};


int main(int argc, char **argv)
{
  auto rose = Flower::create("rose");
  auto lily = Flower::create("lily");
  auto whatTheUserRequested = Flower::create(argv[1]);
}
```

Comment: I think you should not expose the derived classes in the base class. So your factory method should not be in the base class. It should be a separate class with a static function.

Comment: @AbdusSalamKhazi It depends on the situation. For an example piece of code, it's fine. In practice, you'd probably have abstract factories. Or be in a situation where the list of derived classes is fixed, and the very fact that the base class has the factory function gives it reason enough to know about them.

Answer (score 0):

Use a factory function something like this

```
class FlowerFactory
{
    Flower* getFlower(string flowerName)
    {
        if(flowerName == "Rose")
        {
            return new Rose();
        }
        if(flowerName == "Lily")
        {
            return new Lily();
        }
        if(flowerName == "Jasmine")
        {
            return new Jasmine();
        }
    }
}

//Base class
class Flower
{
};

class Jasmine : public Flower
{
    //other things here..

    friend FlowerFactory;
};

class Rose : public Flower
{
    //other things here..

    friend FlowerFactory;
};

class Lily : public Flower
{
    //other things here..

    friend FlowerFactory;
};
```

Answer (score 0):

Are your instructions to not use access specifiers, or that none of your members can be private? If it's the former, you can use `struct` instead of `class` to get public access *by default*. For example:

```
struct Rose : Flower {
    Rose() : Flower(...) {}
    string getColor() const override { return "red"; }
};
```

Comment: @johndoe You say that the only restriction you have is that you can't use the public access specifier. This doesn't​ mean that all your members need to be private or protected. Members of a `struct` are public by default.